# Lograr que los div no pierdan el espacio entre ellos

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Quiero que cuando un div aumente su altura, el espacio que está definido entre ellos no se pierda.

el div de la mitad cuenta con 3 descripciones, el resto solo una, sucede que cuando el div de la mitad tiene las 3, los demás se apartan demasiado 'aumentan su espacio' y no quiero eso, quiero que conserven su espacio.

Ya sé que puedo lograr el efecto uniendo dos div dentro de una caja y poniendo los contenido en fila, pero ya tengo todo armado y no puedo por tiempo y además solo se podría con 1 div en cada fila y necesito los 3 en cada fila.

**Lo que quiero lograr y está usando la app de facebook en estos momentos:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
body{
background-color: #ddd;
}
.caja{
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: start;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background-color: #ff4000;
}
.contenido{
width: 30%;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="caja">

<div class="contenido">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
</div>

<div class="contenido">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
<p>2 descripciones</p>
<p>3 descripciones</p>
</div>

<div class="contenido">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
</div>

<div class="contenido">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
</div>

<div class="contenido">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
</div>


<div class="contenido">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puedes añadir un min-heigth:cantpx; par que todos ocupen la misma altura, te dejo documentación al respecto https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp

Answer (score 0):

Dijiste que querias algo rapido asi que puede que esta no sea la mejor forma, pero podrias probar poniendole espacios en blanco a los `p` con `&nbsp;`, o poniendole una altura minima a cada div, al ser todos de la misma altura, no se van a desordenar.
De nuevo, puede no ser la mejor solucion, pero una rapida...

```css
body{
background-color: #ddd;
}
.caja{
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: start;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background-color: #ff4000;
}
.contenido{
width: 30%;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.alto-minimo{
 min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="caja">

<div class="contenido">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
<p>2 descripciones</p>
<p>3 descripciones</p>
</div>

<div class="contenido">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div class="contenido">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div class="contenido alto-minimo">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
</div>

<div class="contenido alto-minimo">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
</div>


<div class="contenido alto-minimo">
<h2>hola</h2>
<p>descripcion</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```